# Powershell: How to Automatically Populate the Fields of a "Windows Security" Prompt Window to Access a web Page

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer-8, invoke-webrequest

This is my first question on Stack Overflow so please forgive me if it comes off a little vague. In the case that it happens to be, I'll be more than happy to clarify to the best of my ability.

So, I'm trying to automatically login to an IP that requires authorization to do some web scraping. Upon navigating to the URL this window comes up. Is there a method/property that can auto-fill the username/password fields in this window?

[Windows Security Window with Username/Password fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8ivQ.png)

Here's what i have so far

```
function Initialize-IE {
param([system.string]$url,
      [System.Boolean]$isVisible)
$ie = New-Object -ComObject internetexplorer.application
$ie.visible = $isVisible
$ie.navigate($url)
while ($ie.Busy -eq $true) {Start-Sleep -seconds 1;} 
return $ie

}

Initialize-IE -url "10.10.205.63" -isVisible $false
```

On an additional note: I know this is possible to do using invoke-webrequest with the credential parameter. However, there's a button on this web page that requires the user to click on it a number of times in order for an inline script to execute and return the information i need. And the only way that i know of to simulate the button press is through grabbing the element through the internet explorer object and using the click() method. So, if there's an alternative way using the invoke-webrequest method feel free to post it.

Comment: That is not a web page element, so, IVR will not get you there. That is a normal Windows  OS auth prompt being thrown by the authentication config on that site on that web server. So, it's a GUI auth box. SO, this is not a webpage automation use case, it is a GUI automation use case. So, use SendKeys, or other GUI automation tool to do this.

Comment: If the site is hosted on the intranet network then you can try to add the site to the **Trusted site list**. Then after you can go to the `Internet options->Security tab->Local intranet->click the custom level button-> Log on`. Select the **Automatic log-on with current username and password**. [See image here](https://imgur.com/a/ERTa2Yq). It can help you to log in to the site without entering the credentials. So authentication popup will not get displayed while you try to run your Powershell IE automation code.

Comment: Thanks, both of these answers are options I will take into consideration.

Comment: You can test the suggestions and let us know about your test results.

Comment: Since I'm using the script on a computer that has limited permissions I just used postanote's method due to the user's security policy not allowing you to edit internet options without credentials.